# Django Pagination works for first page, does not second page

Tags: python, django

I have a search view that allows user's to search for their notecards, and then displays results paginated 6 at a time.

I use pagination in all my other views and it works correctly. However, when using it with the query it displays the first 6 results, displays "Page 1 of 2" and the next button, but when you click Next you get no results found.

I've setup the '*' query as a search-all, and when I search for that query the first request call is:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=*`

When I click next, the call is:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?page=2`

The search url is:

`url(r'^search/', 'notecard.search.views.search', name="search"),`

The search view is:

```
@login_required(login_url='/auth/login/')
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q', '')
    results = []
    notecard_list = []
    if query:
        if query == "*":
            results = Notecard.objects.filter(section__semester__user=request.user)
        else:
            results = Notecard.objects.filter(Q(section__semester__user=request.user), Q(notecard_body__icontains=query)|Q(notecard_name__icontains=query))
        paginator = Paginator(results, 6)

        try:
            page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
        except ValueError:
            page = 1

        try:
            notecard_list = paginator.page(page)
        except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
            notecard_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return list_detail.object_list(
        request,
        queryset = Notecard.objects.filter(section__semester__user=request.user),
        template_name = "notecards/search.html",
        template_object_name = "results",
        extra_context = {"results": results, "notecard_list": notecard_list,},
    )
```

and the search template is:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} Notecard List | {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div id='main'>
<table id='notecards'>
  <tr>
        <th class="name">Search Results</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id='known_split'>
        <p>Search results:<a class="edit" href="{% url semester_list %}">Back to Semesters</a></p>
            {% for result in notecard_list.object_list %}
                    <tr>
                        <td class="image">{% if result.known %}<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/images/known.png" width="41" height="40" />{% else %}<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/images/unknown.png" width="41" height="40" />{% endif %}</td>
                    <td class="text"><a href="{% url notecards.views.notecard_detail result.id %}">{{ result.notecard_name|truncatewords:9 }}</a></td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
</table>

<div class="pagination">
  <span class="step-links">
{% if notecard_list.has_previous %}
<a class="navlink" href="?page={{ notecard_list.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
{% endif %}

<span class="current">
Page {{ notecard_list.number }} of {{ notecard_list.paginator.num_pages }}
</span>

{% if notecard_list.has_next %}
<a class="navlink" href="?page={{ notecard_list.next_page_number }}">next</a>
{% endif %}
  </span>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

As I said, I use basically the same pagination in every other view successfully, so I have to believe this is due to the query somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You're not providing the `q` argument in the URL for page 2 (the URL should be something like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=*&page=2` instead)
2. You should check out class based views (`ListView` to be more precise), which include [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.paginate_by)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check out the ListView also.

Comment: No prob. Class based views will be daunting at first, but you'll love them after the first week.

Answer (score 2):

Need to include `q` argument in `has_previous & has_next` URL's,

```
<a class="navlink" href="?page={{ notecard_list.previous_page_number }}&q1={{ request.GET.q1 }}">previous</a>
```

and,

```
<a class="navlink" href="?page={{ notecard_list.next_page_number }}&q1={{ request.GET.q1 }}">next</a>
```